# Yii2: How to make validation rule message not to be encoded?

Tags: php, yii2

In base PasswordResetRequestForm model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [               
            ['email', 'exist',
                'targetClass' => '\common\models\User',
                'filter' => ['status' => User::STATUS_ACTIVE],
                'message' => 'Such user is not registered. '.BaseHtml::a('Signup.',['site/signup'])
            ],
        ];
    }
```

But link renders encoded. How to force it not to be encoded? Where should I do it, in ActiveForm, in field config, or in validation rule?

Comment: You should probably also add the code how it gets outputted to the screen. I don't think the validation does html encoding.

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php#L1106 here is the line. It can't be done.

Comment: Have to admit that I never considered adding a link to a validation error, but it kind of makes sense that you would be able to do so. It's a bit annoying that they just assume you won't. Perhaps you should file a ticket and ask for an encode option, they have it everywhere else. Btw you can also just use "Html" instead of BaseHtml, shorter :)

Comment: Thaks! Already pulled/used =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the past, but now you can configure it in the fieldConfig:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'errorOptions' => ['encode' => false],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this on ActiveForm :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'encodeErrorSummary' => false,
]); ?>
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$encodeErrorSummary-detail

Comment: This doesn't work (at least not the error for individual fields within the form).